# Run two .py files simultaneously in a project in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-2019

I have a project in visual studio with two `.py` files named `client.py` and `server.py`. I've to run `server.py` and the `client.py` and none of them should be closed. When I press `F5` and start the project only `server.py` console opens. And when I open them outside the visual studio (I open the `server.py` and then `client.py` to connect them) after opening the `client.py`, it closes the `server.py`. How can I prevent this and make them stay open?
I know there are multiple questions and answers like this out there, but none of them is exactly like this one (I'm not using visual studio code!)

Here is a look at what I'm dealing with: (server is waiting for a client but there is nothing I can do to open the client console window)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by " it closes the server.py"? Two different scripts running in different interpreters shouldn't be interacting with each other unless you have interactions coded between them. Is starting one causing socket errors in the other?

Comment: I think this isn't normal behavior. Are you sure that there aren't any bugs in your server.py that finishes the process when client.py tries to connect?

Comment: @Carcigenicate They're in the same project as I said, so I don't think they're in different interpreters. And yes I have interactions between them. They're client and server after all! :) It doesn't show me any errors when I run them...

Comment: @AlissonCorrea maybe there are bugs there. But I can't debug it because when I press F11 and start debugging, when it reaches the "connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()" it stops for a client and I don't have access to debug the client.py too

Comment: Maybe a try-catch wrapping "connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()" should give you hints

Comment: @AlissonCorrea I'm searching for a way to have a console window for every code. If I test a code that I'm sure about it, still can't open another window when the previous one is still working. This shouldn't be the problem, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still don't know how to do that, I suggest whoever has this problem to run their codes in separate projects and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

*For visual studio code*

- On a new terminal use `Ctrl+Shift+5` to split the terminal... that's it...

[image]

Comment: As I said I don't use visual studio code so it doesn't work for me. And are you sure it is 5 and not F5?

Comment: yes brother...`Ctrl+Shift+5` to split the terminal.....